# Is it possible to make a one2many relation without specifying the target model's "foreign key field"?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

I want to make a `superclass` that have a `one2many` relation with says `dummy.one`. So that every `subclass` that inherit the `superclass` will have a `one2many` relation with `dummy.one`. The problem is declaring a `one2many` relation forces me to specify the foreign key which link `dummy.one` to the `superclass`. Thus I need to create `many2one` relation (foreign key) in `dummy.one` for every `subclass` that I create.

The only trick that works is that I create a `many2many` relation instead of `one2many`.

Here's an example:

```
'dummies'      : fields.one2many('dummy.one','foreign_key','Dummies'),
```

Many2Many:

```
'dummies'      : fields.many2many('dummy.one',string='Dummies'),
```

Is there any better way to achieve the same effect as `many2many` without having to declare a `many2one` field in `dummy.one` for every `subclass`?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using Python inheritance you may prefer to use the Odoo's ORM inheritance which is inheritance by delegation. Please see the following example:

```
class book(models.Model):
    _name = 'books.book'
    name = fields.Char()
    author = fields.Many2one('books.author')

class author(models.Model):
    _name = 'books.author'
    name = fields.Char()
    books = fields.One2many('books.book', 'author')

class better_author(models.Model):
    _name = 'books.author'
    _inherit = 'books.author'
    curriculum = fields.Text()
```

Comment: You can't define a One2many field without its foreign key ('books.book' foreign key to external model). It will say `_o2m_raise_on_missing_reference` `except_orm: ('Programming Error', "There is no reference field 'None' found for 'books.book'")`

Comment: Ok, I just wanted to illustrate my idea and did it quickly. Sorry for the mistake. Please see my updated answer. It still not tested so please be more forgiving about some further errors you may find.

Comment: No worries, It still doesn't work because the `author` field is specified only for `books.author`, there is no connection between `books.book` and `books.better.author`. Btw, it's supposed to be `_name = 'books.better.author` not `_name = 'books.author'`.

Comment: Do you really need to change the `_name` attribute?

Comment: I mean, normally in Odoo we *extend* the functionalities of a model by inheriting it with the same name. If you really need to keep the base model intact and have a new separated inherited model than you are in a trouble with your One2many relation :) Inherited model with new names created new tables in the database (which is not the best design decision). But this should be valid for Many2many relation too...

Comment: Yes I do need to, in my case the parent model needs to be extended by several child models. This is a completely normal thing to do in object oriented programming design which I'm sure you're well aware of. Just like an employee class can be extended by engineers, accountants, marketers, etc. And this I believe is a good design decision because I don't need to rewrite the same functionalities for every class that share those functionalities.

Comment: Odoo can just handle the one2many relation by adding an extra column everytime a class extends the superclass. Just like how it creates a new table everytime a class extends the superclass which is how it goes in the current system.

Now it will even be better if Odoo can support declaration of a field that accepts multiple classes that share a same superclass. Which I believe is hard to implement but possible nonetheless!

Comment: There is a much better design that can handle inheritance.... There is not need of separate field for each subclass - just one additional field called discriminator for example (as in NHIbernate)

Comment: Can you please give me an example for that?

Comment: You create enough columns in the database table corresponding to the base class to to keep the values of all sub-classes. In our example the database table boks_author would have `name` and 'curriculum` columns and additional table for the books' relation. This way you have enough columns to store whatever class or sub-class you want. You just add additional column, let say *class_type* or *discriminator* so to be able to create the right model from the database.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not quite sure what problem you're trying to tackle and which approach you're using right now. If you're still talking about using the one2many field approach that can still be inherited to the subclasses I want to know how I should handle assignation of `books.book` to `books` field in the `books.better.author`. But really an example would be really helpful in this situation.

Comment: I think I know what you're saying, you're talking about how Odoo can handle this one2many field inheritance in the future right? If yes, then you're right a *discriminator* field would be the correct choice, my proposed solution was not so efficient. I don't know if they will do that though. If they rely on postgresql foreign key constraint, they won't be able to set that up because AFAIK postgresql foreign key constraint can't be assigned to many tables.

Answer (score 1):

Try to create a many2one relation (foreign key) in `dummy.one` for the superclass not for every subclass.

Comment: I've tried to do that but it didn't seem to work, odoo doesn't automatically add another foreign key field into `dummy.one`. Have you tried that yourself or you just took a guess?

Answer (score 0):

```
class citys(models.Model):
    _inherit='purchase.order'
    city_partner=fields.One2many('city.line','city_id',string='City')
#relation between type of base class
class city(models.Model):
    _name='city.line'
    city_id=fields.Many2one('purchase.order')
```

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around it. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer.